# Kovri / Sekreta development status

Tags: kovri, i2p

I'd like to know if somebody has a current update on the development status of Kovri. As far as I know Anonimal (the lead dev of Kovri) is currently trying to push [Sekreta](https://gitlab.com/sekreta/sekreta) as an alternative for Kovri.

I really liked the idea of Kovri as a lightweight C++ implementation for I2P. Are there any statements that the community is still committed to finishing Kovri or any reliable information about the dev status? I couldn't get much info about this from their gitlab page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kovri appears to be dead. However, there are two other projects that have been active w.r.t. Monero+i2p ambitions: [i2p-zero](https://github.com/i2p-zero/i2p-zero) and [tini2p](https://gitlab.com/tini2p/tini2p).

There is also now i2p support [merged](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/5091) into the Monero master code and will be in the upcoming point release. Details on the new flags are in [ANONYMITY_NETWORKS](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.md). Once released, you can immediately make use of i2p-zero and Monero (or if you build master, you can make use of this now).

There is no relationship between Sekreta and Monero currently. Note that Sekreta is not an alternative to an i2p implementation, it still relies upon secure networks such as i2p/tor; more information of which can be found in the project [details](https://gitlab.com/sekreta/sekreta).

**UPDATE Jan 2020**

So Anonimal *has* still been working on Sekreta (and Kovri to a lesser extent) - there is now a Monero [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/6276) currently open for review.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! So according to one of your links Tor will also be integrated. Nice. Also tini2p looks really interesting.